# Use function with ggplot2

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

Lets say I've made three plots with this code:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, wt, color = as.factor(cyl))) + geom_point() + scale_color_manual(limits = c("4", "6", "8"), breaks = c("4", "6", "8"), values = c("red", "blue", "green"))

ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg, color = as.factor(cyl))) + geom_point() + scale_color_manual(limits = c("4", "6", "8"), breaks = c("4", "6", "8"), values = c("red", "blue", "green"))

ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, drat, color = as.factor(cyl))) + geom_point() + scale_color_manual(limits = c("4", "6", "8"), breaks = c("4", "6", "8"), values = c("red", "blue", "green"))
```

How can I convert this part of the code to a function called: scale_color_manual(limits = c("4", "6", "8"), breaks = c("4", "6", "8"), values = c("red", "blue", "green"))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take advantage of `%+%`

```
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, wt, color = as.factor(cyl))) + 
         geom_point() + 
         scale_color_manual(limits = c("4", "6", "8"), 
                            breaks = c("4", "6", "8"), 
                            values = c("red", "blue", "green"))

p2 <- aes(hp, mpg, color = as.factor(cyl))

p1 %+% p2

p3 <- aes(hp, drat, color = as.factor(cyl))

p1 %+% p3
```

EDIT

or you can define your scale like:

```
my_scale <-  scale_color_manual(limits = c("4", "6", "8"), 
                                breaks = c("4", "6", "8"), 
                                values = c("red", "blue", "green"))
```

and

```
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, wt, color = as.factor(cyl))) + geom_point()

p1 + my_scale
```

Comment: rawr thats a nice idea but it wouldn't work in my circumstances

Comment: @luciano why not? Could you expand your question to make more clear what you really need.